# Selenium || Python || press button

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium

I have a url with HTML body below ,there should be a drop down menu then after selecting you have to press login button.

using Selenium with Python i managed to automate selecting the desired value from the drop down menu but i can't press the login button

```
enter code here
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

def Open():  

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://xxxxxxx/')
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('timeout'))
select.select_by_value('36000')

Open()
```

**HTML**

```
<HTML> 
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <FORM method=get action="login.php">
    <TABLE BORDER=0>
      <TR>
        <TD>Timeout</TD>
        <TD>
          <SELECT name="timeout">
            <OPTION VALUE="14400"> 4 hours </OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="36000"> 10 hours </OPTION>
          </SELECT>
        </TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD COLSPAN=2>
          <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="LOGIN">
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
  </FORM>
  <FORM method=get action="logout.php">
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="LOGOUT">  
  </FORM>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML and the code? Is that timeout what happens when you try pushing the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the button element then click it. See code below:

```
loginButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='LOGIN']")
loginButton.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The python code that is shown here never attempts to click on any login button.  All it is doing is selecting a value from the dropdown.  Note that you may need to wait until something happens before you do click the login button.